# WooCommerce combine fields for CSV order export

Tags: php, csv, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce Customer/Order CSV Export plugin and would like to use a code snippet in my themes functions.php to create the required CSV format. The next code snippet fills the new columns with data, but I want to combine some of the WooCommerce checkout fields together in column 4, but how do I do that? The outlined code is not working..

`function wc_csv_export_modify_row_data( $order_data, $order, $csv_generator ) {`

```
$custom_data = array(
    'column_1' => '2',
    'column_2' => '302115',
    'column_3' => '[Klant]',
    'column_4' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_first_name', true ),
    /*'column_4' => $order_data['_shipping_first_name'].''.['_shipping_last_name'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_address_1'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_address_2'].'¶'.''.'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_postcode'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_city'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_country'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_billing_email'].'¶'.
                    $order_data['_shipping_company'],*/
    'column_5' => 'SEL'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to do this as well for some of our order exports. Here's how I did it -

```
$custom_data = array(
    // combine first name and last name to 1 field
    'Ship_to_Name' => get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_first_name', true )." ".get_post_meta( $order->id, '_shipping_last_name', true ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer to my question!